# ESXi上の同一VLAN ID＆サブネットの2つの仮想スイッチのトラフィック挙動について

Tags: vmware

下記のように2つの仮想スイッチを構成しています。
物理アダプタそれぞれの対向は同じL2スイッチです。

**仮想スイッチ構成**

[image: 仮想スイッチ構成]

想定として、以下の動作を行うと思っていました。

- ESXiのマネジメント接続での通信はvSwitch0（vmnic0）経由
- 仮想マシンの通信はvSwitch1（vmnic1）経由

しかし、実際のトラフィック状況をSNMPで取得して確認すると、想定と違い2つのパターンとも「vmnic0」経由で流れていることが分かりました。

想定通り個々の物理アダプタ経由での通信とならないのはどのような理由が考えられるでしょうか。

なお、現状では以下の制約があります。

- ESXiへのManagement接続は仮想マシンと同一のサブネットである必要がある
- ESXiへのManagement接続と仮想マシンとの接続は別々の物理アダプタとする必要がある

ESXiへのManagement接続アドレスを管理用の別セグメントに変更することで解決出来そうなのですが、すぐに構成変更することが現状困難なため、インパクトの少ない設定修正等で解決出来ないかと考えております。

宜しくお願いいたします。

※追記※
その後、原因らしきことが分かりましたので補足します。

データストアの1つでNFSを利用しており、NFSサーバは仮想マシンのサブネットと同じネットワーク上の物理サーバとなっています。
仮想マシンでNFSデータストア上の仮想ディスクを使用していました。

推察なのですが、
ESXiとNFSサーバとの通信がVMkernel NICの「vmk0」で行われており、そのため物理NICのvmnic0を通したトラフィックが発生しているものと考えています。

また、再度「vmnic1」のトラフィック状況を確認したところ、上記NFSデータストア上の仮想ディスクと関わらない通信についてはトラフィックが発生していることが確認出来ました。

上記推察の通りだとすると、「vmnic0」でWebクライアントなどのマネジメント接続以外のトラフィックが発生してしまうのは避けられないということになるでしょうか。
NFSデータストアとの通信を「vmnic1」経由とすることはできるでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NFSデータストアの通信は仮想マシンではなくESXiホストの通信なのでvmkernelインターフェースが通信します。vmkernelインターフェースはvSwitch0/vmnic0側の1つしかありませんので当然vmnic0側にトラフィックが流れます。

なので、

> ESXiのマネジメント接続での通信はvSwitch0（vmnic0）経由
> 仮想マシンの通信はvSwitch1（vmnic1）経由

という「想定」通りの通信が行われています。

(この時点ではホスト/仮想マシン/NFSサーバのIPアドレスが何であるかは全く関係ありません)

vmnic1側にNFSトラフィックを流すにはvSwitch1/vmnic1側にvmkernelインターフェースを作ればよいのですが、ここでIPアドレスが問題になります。vSwitch(vmnic)0/1が同一のIPサブネット=複数のvmkernelインターフェースが同一サブネットとなり、どちらのvmkernelインターフェースが通信に使われるかを「適切に」制御することはESXiの仕様でできません。

一番簡単な解決方法は、vSwitch1側にvmk1を作り、vmk0側のネットワークを別IPサブネットにする、ということになります。

Answer (score 0):

回答としては不可能です。

NFSサーバが、
・Management / VM network それぞれにインタフェースを持つ
・1個のIPアドレスでNFSをホストする
ことが両立しません。

構成変更しましょう。